# Is it possible to boost up views/indexes creation in couchdb by multiple cores?

Tags: couchdb

We have just converted a database of app run-time logs from MySQL to CouchDB. There are around 3M docs converted, occupy around 7GB.

Then we scripted out our first view (with reduce function) and did a query to invoke the first run of that view, make out a view creation/generation. It should take some time and I just did a 'top' on that machine to see process/cpu load stuff. I just noticed that there are 2 heavy process:

```
beam.smp 
couchjs
```

It's interesting that they seems to occupy one core, even there are 4 cores on that machine. Is it possible to make couchdb make use of multiple cores while creating/updating views?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently this is not supported. My guess is that good multicore support will add complexity to CouchDB.

So far, CouchDB always chooses simplicity instead of features. (Did you know that CouchDB is only 18,000 lines of code? Compare with [1 million in MySQL](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/#combine_reports) or [100,000 in SQLite](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/#combine_reports).)

When a design document view index is building, it uses one `couchjs` process. If you have multiple design documents, then those *will* run in parallel. CouchDB will spawn one `couchjs` process per design document, and the OS will spread them across multiple cores.

**However**, if you really need performance, [BigCouch](https://github.com/cloudant/bigcouch) is Apache CouchDB-compatible and *does* support parallelized view index building using an oversharded architecture.

Comment: It's really amazing to see lines of code comparison. Thanks for your sharing of this information. You mentioned "simplicity instead of features". Does that mean it is still not that ready for production usage cause there are lots of issues in production environment.

Comment: CouchDB is (intentionally) small and simple, however the things it does **are** ready for production and it **is** being used in production now.

Comment: Is it possible to create views of views?  And then in some cases have your views built in parallel?